# mysql query to count posts

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm creating a database and a need a query that will calculate the amount of posts an editor has made on  a blog, including the blog title and editor username. I am using this statement:

```
SELECT Post.post_Title,
       Post.post_Author, 
       Editor.ed_UsrName, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Post.post_Author = Editor.ed_UsrName THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
          AS numrev
FROM Post
INNER JOIN Editor
ON Post.post_Author=Editor.ed_UsrName;
```

BUT returning this output:

```
+------------+-------------+------------+--------+

| post_Title | post_Author | ed_UsrName | numrev |

+------------+-------------+------------+--------+

|-- Post1 --     | --- user1 ----      | -----user1----      |  ---    3 ----|

+------------+-------------+------------+--------+
```

Im not sure whether ive approached it completely wrong or if its just a case of something small.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the input, I think we're going to struggle to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT Post.post_Title, Post.post_Author, Editor.ed_UsrName, count(1) AS numrev 
FROM Post 
INNER JOIN Editor ON Post.post_Author=Editor.ed_UsrName
group by Editor.ed_UsrName;
```